# Select no se resetea

Tags: jquery, html5, trigger

LLeno varios `<select>` junto con otros `<input>` dentro de un `<form>` en una ventana modal con datos del servidor.
El mismo formulario lo utilizo para mostrar los datos de un registro seleccionado y para ingresar uno nuevo.

Después de mostrar un registro seleccionado, al salir del modal, quiero resetear todos los `<input>` y `<select>` y dejarlo preparado por si quieren ingresar un registro nuevo.

Para ello utilizo `$('#id_miformulario')[0].reset();` y también `$('#id_miformulario').trigger('reset');` pero resetea sólo los `<input>`, los `<select>` los deja con el texto traído desde el servidor en la consulta.

Utilicé `$('#id_miinput').text('');` para resetear los `<select>` y lo hace pero entonces no carga los datos por defecto desde el servidor.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Para ti, ¿qué es "resetear" un select?, ¿vaciarle todas las opciones que tiene dentro ó establecer su valor a uno predeterminado?

Comment: En el caso de los inputs quiero "vaciarles" el contenido y en los selects vaciarles el contenido y que se haga el populate del mismo como al principio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espero que te sea útil y sea lo que necesités realizar...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- Librería Jquery, no es necesario si ya la importaste desde tus assets locales -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="id_miformulario">
        <input type="text" id="a" />
        <input type="text" id="b" />
        <input type="text" id="c" />
        <select id="">
            <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
        <select id="">
            <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
        <!-- Puedes llamar a la función cuando salgás del modal -->
        <input type="button" onclick="limpiar();" value="Limpiar" />
    </form>
</body>

</html>

<script>
    function limpiar() {
        // Esto es lo que estás haciendo en tu código para los inptus así que lo aplique
        $('#id_miformulario')[0].reset();
        // Elige alguna de estas dos formas
        // Por medio de jquery accedes a los select y remueves la propiedad de seleccionado (selected)
        $("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
        // Si te das cuenta en los select tengo una opcion con un value "" (Seleccionar), 
        // entonces pongo el valor a "" para que el selected se posicione en esa opción
        $("option:selected").val = ""
    }
</script>**texto en negrita**
```

Comment: Gracias por el código Lud voy a probarlo y te comento